# SCCM. I'm studying for exam 70-243 and can't figure out the answer to this. I believe it to be SysPrep.

Tags: sccm

Anyone know the correct answer? See my explanation at the end......

Your network contains a System Center 2012 Configuration Manager.

You plan to create a Build and Capture task sequence to build a reference image of Windows 7.

You need to identify which Application must exist in Configuration Manager before you can create the Build and Capture task sequence.

Which Applications should you identify? (Choose all that Apply.)

A. Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)

B. Configuration Manager client

C. System Preparation tool (Sysprep)

D. User State Migration Tool (USMT) 
Answer: B 
Your answer: C 
Explanation: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb633062.aspx How to Create

Personal comment: 
My personal opinion is that this question is flawed and other than the Configuration Manager console, you do not need any special application to create the task. However, as someone else has stated: You should ALWAYS use MDT for building, capturing and testing your reference images Tool to capture an image from reference computer. So for all intents and purposes, MDT is the most likely answer to this question: http://www.windows- noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/5131-using-sccm- 2012-rc-in-a-lab-part-16-integratingmdt- 2012-rc1-with-configuration-manager-2012/ 
MDT, Microsoft Deployment Toolkit Install MDT and run Configure Configmgr intergration In Management Console, SW lib, OS, Task Sequence, Create MDT task sequence , choose a template ( client task sequence),

Comment: I don't know about this specific exam, so this is more a personal opinion: MDT is never needed by sccm. Many people will integrate and use it, but it is far from necessary for anything so it should never be the answer to a question. USMT is never needed for a Build and Capture either. Now for the other 2: There has to be a PACKAGE for the client and a PACKAGE for the Sysprep. The client one you can specify, the sysprep one is implicit (you can still see it if you search). If those do not exist it will not work. Of course they exist out of the box but maybe those packages is what they ask about

Comment: I thought the answer was SysPrep. I didn't think you had to have the Manger Client?

Comment: If you create a Build and Capture TS the installation of the client on the System you capture is a step it won't let you skip in the wizard, so I assume you need it. Of course it has not to be installed on the server but is has to be present in form of a package. You could remove the step after the wizard but I am not sure how well that would work out for the capturing

Answer (score 0):

The ConfigMan client is needed for the TS, sys prep would be used in the capture step but I believe it uses the built in one that is on the OS disk/ISO. MDT and USMT aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a Configuration Manager Client package. Sysprep package is only necessary for XP deployments as Vista and Windows 7 already have sysprep included. MDT and USMT are not needed.